# Are there any scientific journals about meta-analysis?

Tags: meta-analysis, references

I'm searching about scientific journals which are oriented only about meta-analysis. I knew there were some but i can't find any both searching google and http://www.scimagojr.com/journalrank.php

Are there any journals oriented all about meta-analysis?

Comment: There are even meta-analyses of meta-analysis research studies, but they are quite hard to search since queries "meta-analysis of meta-analysis" in most cases returns garbage results.

Comment: I usually stumbled across that type of works searching with the queries "meta-meta-analysis" or "meta-epidemiological study" but the second term is a bit less specific

Comment: Yes, and it adequately leads to xkcd: https://xkcd.com/1447/ :)

Comment: @GGA Do you mean: Journals that focus on **methods** for meta-analysis or journals that focus on publishing applied meta-analyses (usually with focus on a particular discipline)?

Comment: Journals that focus in methods

Comment: _Research Synthesis Methods_ and _Systematic Reviews_ were already mentioned by mdewey and their focus is clear. _Statistics in Medicine_ also publishes a fair bit on meta-analysis and so does _BMC Medical Research Methodology_ and the _Journal of Clinical Epidemiology_. In fact, most journals focused on statistical methods have published at least some articles on meta-analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is the journal Research Synthesis Methods

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/(ISSN)1759-2887

there is also an open access journal dedicated to systematic reviews

http://systematicreviewsjournal.biomedcentral.com/

but it does not publish much on meta-analysis methods as far as I can see.

Of course medical statistics journals also publish occasionally in this field but they are not dedicated to it.